# ssh server disconnects after getting logged in

Tags: linux, ssh, vpn, mac-osx

Having no prior knowledge of servers and ssh I recently had to connect to ssh server to escape from the government's censorship of the internet(use an ssh server as a vpn) but as I try to connect to the server It connects and then immediately disconnects. I couldn't come up with an answer that suits my situation.

also the servers I used are free ones from the internet from websites like serverssh.net, etc. I'm using mac.

`❯ ssh username@server`

```
<h3><font color='black'>SERVERSSH.NET
</font></h3>
<h3><font color='blue'>JAGOANSSH.COM
</font></h3>
username@server password: 
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-193-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

 System information disabled due to load higher than 1.0

 * Super-optimized for small spaces - read how we shrank the memory
   footprint of MicroK8s to make it the smallest full K8s around.

   https://ubuntu.com/blog/microk8s-memory-optimisation

6 updates can be applied immediately.
To see these additional updates run: apt list --upgradable

New release '20.04.5 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.



The programs included with the Ubuntu system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Ubuntu comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by
applicable law.


The programs included with the Ubuntu system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Ubuntu comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by
applicable law.

Last login: Mon Sep 26 16:12:09 2022 from *.*.*.*
Could not chdir to home directory /home/username: No such file or directory
Connection to server closed.
```

`❯ /usr/sbin/sshd -d`

```
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_8.6, LibreSSL 3.3.6
debug1: Unable to load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
debug1: Unable to load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
debug1: Unable to load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
sshd: no hostkeys available -- exiting.
```

`❯ ssh -vvv username@server`

```
.
.
.

debug3: send packet: type 1
debug3: fd 1 is not O_NONBLOCK
Connection to server closed.
Transferred: sent 2272, received 5272 bytes, in 2.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 1095.3, received 2541.5
debug1: Exit status 1
```

Comment: looks like you are missing host keys on the server.  you can run this (and then restart the daemon) `ssh-keygen -A`.  you should also try to install the official ubuntu openssh package, which will get updates, and should have configured this for you.

Comment: @toppk thanks installed openssh from homebrew and ran the shell command you specified but no error changed

Comment: you need hostkeys, there are some instructions here. 
 https://www.softec.lu/site/DevelopersCorner/HowToRegenerateNewSsh